# How to Upload user profile picture in firebase after login?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I  upload profile Image into Firebase Storage,
[database Screen shot with user info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRvl1.png)
then I get image URL to store in to Firebase real-time database . When i store imagurl into Firebase realtime database specific user than i see my Userprofile all user data remove and repleas imgurl link [image url replease screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxzWW.png).

**I Want to upload imgurl in to "UserProfile" by userID (I create UserID by UserPhone Number)**

```
de
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_pic_change);

    Folder = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("UserImag");

    profileImg = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

    fbprofile = findViewById(R.id.fabProfile);

    FullNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("User");
    nidverifybtn=findViewById(R.id.Nidverifybtn);
    changeProfileImg = findViewById(R.id.upload_profile_img);

    nidverifybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (getUserStatus.equals("Not Verify")){
                        nidverifybtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NIDVerificationScreen.class);
                        intent.putExtra("FullNumber",FullNumber);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        nidverifybtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });

    fbprofile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImagePicker.Companion.with(ProfilePicChange.this)
                    .crop()                 //Crop image(Optional), Check Customization for more option
                    .cropOval()             //Allow dimmed layer to have a circle inside
                    .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)  //Final image resolution will be less than 1080 x 1080(Optional)
                    .start(10);
        }
    });



}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode==10){
        profile = data.getData();
        profileImg.setImageURI(profile);

        StorageReference Imagename = Folder.child(FullNumber).child(profile.getLastPathSegment());
        Imagename.putFile(profile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Imagename.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        DatabaseReference ImageStore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserProfiles");
                        HashMap<String, String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("ProfileImage", String.valueOf(uri));

                        ImageStore.setValue(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                Toast.makeText(ProfilePicChange.this, "Complated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Select Profile Picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `id`phone number to this part of your code:

```
DatabaseReference ImageStore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserProfiles");
```

to

```
DatabaseReference ImageStore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserProfiles").child(phoneNumber);
```

I'm not aware of the context of the app but.
**WARNING:** I would strongly recommend not to use a phone number as user identifier. Instead use the autogenerated User `uid`. Phone numbers can change and the auth `uid` stays unique globaly.

Comment: please check this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68963376/how-to-get-image-url-from-firebase-storage-in-android-studio

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: I got solution so i delete link

Comment: Sir, please check this and help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68994035/how-can-set-amount-validation-in-android-java